# Angular 4 сборка проэкта для node

Tags: angular4

Вопрос в том что при создание проэкта на Angular все создаеться отдельной папкой. И во время разроботки хватает локального сервера который запускаеться через `npm start` (Это без cli). Вопрос в том как связать эту страницу и сделать на неё роутинг через свой сервер написаный на node. Полазив по инету я наткнулся на инфу о сборщиках(Вроде gulp). Но я не совсем понимаю нужен ли он в данной ситуации и если нужен то есть ли сылочка на то как использовать его для Angular 4 проэктов.

Comment: вам точно нужно отдавать ангуляр с сервера ноды?

Comment: Как я понимаю Angular  это фронтэнд  а noda бекэнд. Тогда как соеденить их вместе

Comment: И как тогда разворачивать проэкт на хосте

Comment: просто раздавать статику. Собрать для prod и залить на хостинг. Все. Только нужно настроить для SPA хостинг